# Continuity of the function

Tags: limits, continuity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xamUw.jpg)$$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2y+x^3}{x^4+(y+x)^2}$$

Is the function continuous at $(0,0)$?

thanks

Comment: You haven't specified both the domain and range of the function.

Comment: Why do you keep reverting the edit?

Comment: @user170039 I corrected the inaccuracy

Comment: @StubbornAtom i was inaccurate on Domain

Answer (score 1):

For people who don't like to have to open links, the function given is $f(x, y)= \frac{x^2y+ x^3}{x^4+ (y+ x)^2}$. Do you even know the **definition** of "continuous" at a point?  If you do, then you should have immediately see that the simplest way to show that this is not continuous at $(0, 0)$ is to note that it is NOT DEFINED at $(0,0)$!

However, I suspect that you were also given that $f(0, 0)= 0$.  For a problem like this, the simplest way to show that a function **is** continuous at $(0, 0)$ is to change to polar coordinates.  That way the distance from $(0, 0)$ is measured by the single variable r.  In polar coordinates, $x= r cos(\theta)$ and $y= r sin(\theta)$ so $\frac{x^2y+ x^3}{x^4+ (y+ x)^2}= \frac{r^3cos^2(\theta)sin(\theta)+ r^3cos^3(\theta)}{r^4\cos^4(\theta)+ (rcos(\theta)+ rsin(\theta)^2}=  \frac{r^3(cos(\theta)sin(\theta)+ cos^3(\theta)}{r^2(r^2cos^2(\theta)+ (cos(\theta)+ sin(\theta))^2}$.  As long as r is not 0, we can cancel to get $f(x,y)= r\frac{cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\theta)+ cos^3(\theta)}{r^2cos^4(\theta)+ (sin(\theta)+ cos(\theta))^2}$

Because or the "r" in front, that will go to $0$ as r goes to $0$ no matter what $\theta$ is.  IF the function is defined so that $f(0, 0)= 0$, then it is continuous there.  Otherwise it is not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .
I know the definition of continuity but are not able to eliminate the dependence of " r " . I know that the result is that the function is not continuous . I thought it was to demonstrate an alternative route along two different limit ( no continuity) .it's right? I do not know how to do.

Comment: That's an incorrect answer. $f(x,x^2-x) = 1/2.$